# Add drag resistance to MotionEvent when dragging upwards

Tags: android, kotlin, drag, motionevent, pan

I am using `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` to drag a view up or down on the y axis. The dragging works perfectly, however, I would like to add some 'resistance' when the drag is UP.

Here is my progress thus far.

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

    downYValue = event.y

    rightDY = viewToDrag!!.y - event.rawY
}
MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

    val displacement = ((event.rawY) + rightDY)

    println("DISPLACEMENT $displacement")

    val currentY = event.y
    if (downYValue > currentY) {
        println("up")
    }

    viewToDrag!!.animate().y(displacement).setDuration(0).start()
}
```

When the view is dragged either up or down, the drag speed is the same as the finger speed.

I would like for the UPWARD drag to drag much slower than your finger speed. The closet I got was detecting "up".

**How can I add resistance to the upward drag speed?**

Comment: A simple way is rather than animating the full displacement, animate some percentage of it.  Say 50%.  That way you'd travel at half speed.  Play with it until it feels right.  Make sure whenever you set a y location after that that you use the one with the percentage displacement, not the raw y of the event.

Comment: I wouldn't `animate` the view, touch events are delivered often enough (I think even more than once per draw) so it's only going to add unnecessary delay. I don't see your entire concept but point to consider is that you should also displace reverse motion of dragging down (after dragging up) or otherwise it will be possible to "wiggle away" the view.

Comment: @GabeSechan If I do something like `val displacement = ((event.rawY) + rightDY)/2` , the view jumps as soon as I begin dragging.